# Stack trace reference in Salesforce Commerce Cloud

Tags: error, sandbox, logging, commerce-cloud, stacktrace

On my sandbox, in my logs, I got an error and I got a reference to the stack trace of the error:

> Stack trace
>
> `<ref:a6d7f20c52ed080c41c1e8e66b1bac4f>`

Is it possible to find the stack trace itself on sandbox or somewhere else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the **Development Setup** module found in the nav under **Administration >  Site Development**. Within the "WebDAV Access" section, you'll see a subsection for "Log Files". There are two ways to access them.

## Log Center

First, and ideally you have Log Center access for the instance you're trying to check logs for. There should be a "Log Center" link below the WebDAV URL for logs. Click this link. Once the Log Center interface loads, do a search with that value minus the `<ref:` and `>` characters. Wrapped with `stacktraceUUID:( )` It should show you all relevant logs w/ that stack trace. For example:

```
stackTraceUUID: ( a6d7f20c52ed080c41c1e8e66b1bac4f )
```

You can also just search for that hashed string. It's relatively unique so the likelihood of finding something irrelevant is low.

## WebDAV

Alternatively, you can find the stack trace in one of the log files. They are separated by severity and by custom code vs native code.

### Error and Debug Logs

Typically you'll want to check (in this order until you know better)

- customerror-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- error-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- customdebug-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- debug-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log

#### Example

- customerror-blade3-0.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723
- error-blade3-0.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723
- customdebug-blade3-2.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723
- debug-blade3-2.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723

### Job Logs

If the error occurred in a Job there is a special category for those messages:

- jobs-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log

### Service Logs

Similarly if the error occurred in a Service context there is a special category for each service:

- service--blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log

#### Example

- service-marketingcloud-blade3-0.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723.log
- service-servicecloud-blade3-0.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-20190723.log

### Warn and Info Logs

You won't typically find stack traces in warnings and info messages, but it is good to check them periodically for some code smells.

- customwarn-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- warn-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- custominfo-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log
- info-blade#-#.mon.demandware.net-0-appserver-.log

### Decyphering the Patterns

The `blade#-#` pattern refers to the physical architecture of the server instances.  This pattern is present on SIG instances such as 'traditional' sandboxes and PIG Development instances still, despite always being the same value. On PIG instances like Staging and Production you'll typically see at least one blade for Staging and at least three blades for Production. For example:

```
blade3-0
blade3-1
blade3-2
```

### Notes

- Log entries are limited for identical recurrences within a certain time period.
- Downloading log files counts against contractual data transfer agreements and can potentially cause overage charges for some contracts. Avoid setting up watch processes that continually download entire log files.